# Can we merge [vsts-online] tag with [vsts]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retag-request

Can someone merge the [vsts-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-online) with [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts), as we can see all the other synonyms [vso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vso) & [visual-studio-online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) already merged?

Comment: This should probably in this discussion here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373920/vsts-has-been-renamed-to-azure-devops-lets-talk-about-some-tags