# VSTS has been renamed to Azure DevOps - let's talk about some tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

> #### Progress update, 2018-09-11
>
> To avoid losing information while this discussion is in progress, most tag mergers described below have been postponed; however, the vsts tags *have* been renamed as follows:
>
> ```
> vsts-release-task -> azure-pipelines-release-task
> vsts-local-build-agent -> azure-devops-self-hosted-agent
> vsts-extension -> azure-devops-extensions
> vsts-package-management -> azure-artifacts
> vsts-api -> azure-devops-rest-api
> vsts-build-task -> azure-pipelines-build-task
> vsts-release -> azure-pipelines-release-pipeline
> vsts-build -> azure-pipelines
> vsts -> azure-devops
> ```

So, [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts) [is now Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-devops/). While this change has been a *little* controversial, it's kind of nice that folks like Microsoft realize that Stack Overflow needs to be kept up to date and that work comes from volunteers.

We've been in touch with our friends there (disclaimer: they are a client and do sponsor VSTS along with quite a few other tags on the site) to discuss the best way to handle the change on our end. We wanted to make sure that *y'all* didn't shoulder the brunt of the re-tagging work, and that we left some opportunity to bring up any caveats.

They worked with us to hammer out a plan and some synonyms. Here's what we came up with together, broken down by area of responsibility:

Legend: [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/existing) | `proposed`

#### Stack Overflow Employees:

- We'll mass-rename [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts) to be `azure-devops`.
- We'll mass-rename [vsts-release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-release) to be `azure-pipelines`.
- We'll create a synonym, with [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts) pointing to `azure-devops`.
- We'll create synonyms: [vsts-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-build), [vsts-build-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-build-task), [vsts-build-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-build-agent) pointing to `azure-pipelines`

That's approximately 95% of the heavy lifting done.

#### Microsoft Employees:

Microsoft has folks active in all related tags with enough rep to handle the remainder of stuff, which includes:

- Editing tag wiki / tag info excerpts
- Making a sweep of quite a few of the tagged questions to make sure the right tags are there
- Updating *some* external links (there shouldn't be much of this needed)

#### Folks active / vested in any of these tags:

- Look out for broken things.
- Sanity check our hare-brained scheme, here.

That's it, essentially. Don't feel like you *can't* jump into editing tag wikis and stuff, or fixing links, just take care to know that our friends over at Microsoft aren't presuming you will, so they'll actively be working on it.

Does anyone see any major problems with how we've got this laid out? I'm going to let this soak until late today / tomorrow to get any last feedback before I fire up the TagMutator3000.

I *think* we can do this quickly enough to make it appear to be atomic from most outsider's perspectives, so there shouldn't be a need to blacklist or warn prior to creating the synonyms.

With under 7k total affected *visible* questions, this isn't the biggest undertaking we've ever done, but it's definitely going on the list of big ones.

Did we miss anything? A hat tip again to our friends over at Microsoft, all too often these things hit without any warning or planning *at all*, the brief head's-up saved a *lot* of confusion and double work by volunteers.

Comment: @GrantWinney I am pretty sure that the joke is wrong.

Comment: There are a bunch of other [vsts-*] tags out there, do you also plan on renaming those?

Comment: @Stijn I think so, but some of them might not actually be _needed_, so I'm going to post a list of whatever we weren't quite sure what to do with. I think the _majority_ of them will just be synonyms, but we're okay to leave some for folks more actively using it to bring up naturally, if that makes sense.

Comment: Is combining `vsts-release` and `vsts-build` into the same `azure-pipelines` tag going to cause confusion? It sounds like it could making searching for information more difficult.

Comment: @Calidus That's .. one of the things I was hoping to suss out by requesting feedback prior. That might be well suited as an answer here.

Comment: What's the difference between renaming and then creating a synonym, and just creating a synonym? Isn't the end result the same?

Comment: Please ask devops questions at [DevOps Stack Exchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). We don't need more off-topic crap here. How many times do we have to endure questions like how to operate a terminal, how to ssh into the cloud, how to make a backup, how to provision a disk and vm, etc.

Comment: "Updating some external links (there shouldn't be much of this needed)" - Microsoft links break all the time (KB numbers? Microsoft Connect?), please be thorough.

Comment: @jww Just because it’s called “Azure DevOps” that doesn’t mean that it is _only_ DevOps. Many parts of that (source control, build and release management) are very much on-topic here.

Comment: I can't believe they've renamed this product again. We've been using it for about four years and in that time it's been TFS Online, Visual Studio Online, Visual Studio Team Services and now Azure DevOps. It genuinely confuses the management where I work and whilst that's a trival problem it's still a problem. Still the heads-up from MS is welcome.

Comment: @GrantWinney I'm inclined to think they spend more on renaming.

Comment: @jww [Devops.SE] doesn't have an [on topic definition](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) yet. It is nowhere near ready for general recommendation. Besides, DevOps is not a field. It's a coordination mindset between two fields that have (rather wrongly) been siloed from each other traditionally. The idea of being a "dev ops expert" holds about as much weight as being an "agile expert."

Comment: @TimPost Grammar Nazi here. It is harebrained.. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harebrained. Cheers

Comment: @PhilipStratford For what it is worth, TFS is still called TFS, at least for now.

Comment: @jww: Programming can and does factor into DevOps workflows, so some amount of overlap is inevitable. It mostly depends on the context of the question.

Comment: @TylerH: Nope. It's going to be "Azure DevOps Server", though that probably won't come until the next major release. Getting everyone to update TFS just to change the name is an untenable prospect to say the least.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Operative phrase is "for now", see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/what-happened-vsts?view=vsts#what-about-team-foundation-server-tfs

Comment: @PhilipStratford: The reason for the change is supposedly to broaden the market for the components formerly collectively called VSTS. From what I read, they want to remove the confusion that you need to use Visual Studio to use something like build and release, work items, repositories, etc. You will supposedly be able to take just the pieces you want and use whatever else you like for the rest. You could kind of do this *already*, but it wasn't as obvious.

Comment: @GrantWinney, when was the last renaming?

Comment: @BlueClouds This summary on Wikipedia gives you an idea of the renamings that have taken place and when. All of the products with the "Cloud" value in the Form column are basically the same thing with a new name each time (although obviously the product has evolved hugely in that time). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server#History

Comment: I wish, when talking to an international audience, people would default to yyyy-mm-dd, or dd-mon-yyyy

Comment: Hey Tim, just a whinge: can you please **not** use American format dates in your update - I think most SO members would understand ISO format.

Comment: @slugster I blame Shog for that (as he swooped in to handle this while I was out of the office unexpectedly while precariously juggling kittens with a bottle of tequila and a chainsaw) :P But I've updated it.

Comment: renaming a few tags and "approximately 95% of the heavy lifting done." If Microsoft bought that then they are just being nice. Tags renaming should not take more than 2 minutes typing work

Comment: @BlueClouds ........ huh? You kinda lost me there.

Comment: @TimPost I've opened a new bug [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374091/tags-coincide-with-the-ads). Not sure about the root cause.Might think you can look into this

Comment: Let's just call it `Azure DOS`.

Comment: Taking about rename roulette - why don't you rename the TagMutator3000 to **MS Azure DevOps TagMutator 3000** ?  I like the name ... :-D

Comment: How about **MS Azure DevOps Tag Pipeline Pipeline Mutator 3000 Pipeline Branch**?

Comment: @vandre: It's both. See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hare-brained%2Charebrained&year_start=2000&year_end=2008 and the appropriate wiktionary entries. A news search shows a slight popularitiy difference.

Comment: @TimPost Is this still in need of featuring?

Comment: I've sometimes commented that a question doesn't need to be included in the tags, there's 30K room for the text. Now it looks like a new azure tag contains the entire question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How much effort (hours) does the renaming process take?

Comment: @ftl A few hours at least. You've got to go through everything tagged and make sure there are no other issues and make sure the synonyms you're creating make sense (which means the tags are used consistently). The actual update of the database takes only a second or two, it's the sanity that takes a while.

Comment: so this is the new TFS..?

Comment: I couldn't help but notice the progress update says `vsts-release -> azure-pipelines-release-pipeline` but the body of the post says "We'll mass-rename `vsts-release` to be `azure-pipelines`"

Comment: Isn't there already also completely unrelated thing in Azure named a "DevOps Project?"

Comment: You could abbreviate the tag to ADO... [oh wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ado). Reminds me of MVC again (Microsoft Visual C or Model View Controller)?

Answer (score 102):

```
vsts-release -> azure-pipelines-release-pipeline
vsts-build -> azure-pipelines
```

That seems oddly inconsistent. Why not:

```
vsts-release -> azure-pipelines-release
vsts-build -> azure-pipelines-build
```

?

Comment: Especially taking `vsts-release-task -> azure-pipelines-release-task  and  
vsts-build-task -> azure-pipelines-build-task` into consideration

Comment: Stumbled upon that to and I think your suggestion should really be taken into consideration

Comment: This seems to make a lot of sense

Answer (score 59):

Build and Release overlap but not perfectly. There are build and release specific tasks as well as them have different predefined variables, and interact with agents differently. Combining them into a single tag is going double the search area for users when they are trying to find a solution. That might not be huge right now with 7k visible questions, but what does look like a year or two in the future? Is there any benefit to the stack overflow user for having these two tag combined into one?

Can tags be hierarchical? Could `azure-pipelines` contain `azure-pipelines-build` and `azure-pipelines-release`?

There is also `vsts-api` that will need renamed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-5.0

Comment: Tags cannot be hierarchical, but we could probably use azure-pipelines-build and azure-pipelines-release - anyone wishing to follow both could follow `azure-pipelines-*`

Comment: @Shog9 it'd be interesting to see how many users know you can do that or *would* do that even if aware.

Comment: About three thousand users have 36 thousand-some saved wildcard tags, @JonClements.

Comment: @Shog9 I still think that we are failing at UX.

Comment: @Braiam: wildcard search is _good_ UX for developers..

Comment: @awe usability and discoverability are two aspects of UX

Comment: Is it documented anywhere? I mean, the whole wildcard tag thing (I don't care about VTST or whatever it's called today).

Comment: @Braiam Yes, wel.. maybe it is only for database developers wildcard is an intuitive and self-explanatory thing - and then the wildcard character should rather be `%`

Comment: // , I've seen this pretty often, especially when my job was "release" and someone else's job was "build"

Answer (score 27):

I note from the linked article that Team Foundation Server is also to be renamed

> Starting with next version of TFS, the product will be called Azure DevOps Server and will continue to be enhanced through our normal cadence of updates.

so I think that the idea that "95% of the heavy lifting done" may be an underestimate.

(FWIW, I think renaming an on premise product into the Azure brand is going to cause no end of confusion)

Comment: The next release could well be months away. I guess this rename will go on the tag shuffle backlog and will become of concern once the release has dropped.

Comment: It's not the re-branding, that causes the confusion. The confusion as to what [cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) really is has always existed. Until now, the notion of *the cloud* being *the internet* has been widespread. While incorrect, it didn't have any immediate bearing on securing intellectual assets. There was VSTS, and there was the cloud. The re-branding forces clients (and managers in particular) to re-align their understanding of cloud computing with reality. That's not a bad thing, even if it won't go unnoticed.

Comment: @IInspectable, I don't get it. VSTS was always MS-hosted (and thus "cloud"), while TFS is local, in the same way that Office 365's mail is MS-hosted Exchange (and thus "cloud"), while Exchange Server is local. The re-branding podiluska's talking about is essentially a name that means Cloud Local Server, which is silly and contradictory. Just because Azure is a big part of MS's current strategy doesn't mean it needs to have its name applied to things that aren't really Azure. Remember when they did that with the .NET name, including calling the Microsoft Account a .NET Passport?

Comment: @mat: *"VSTS"* in my previous comment was meant to read *"TFS"*. Still, *"Cloud Local Server"* is only *"silly and contradictory"*, if you introduce an invalid meaning to *"cloud computing"*. The term *"own cloud"* has existed for so long, that I'm genuinely confused by people attributing *"cloud computing"* to 3rd-party, web-hosted platforms only. At any rate, the point I was making: The confusion will end, and if the re-branding triggers discussion that leads to a better understanding, then that is a Good Thing, even if just by coincidence.

Comment: @IInspectable How is calling two different flavours of the same product the same thing going to "lead to a better understanding"? "Azure" will now sometimes have its original meaning of "hosted by Microsoft as a service, rather than on-premises", and sometimes just mean "sold by a Microsoft department who think that the word Azure is cool". Meanwhile, people will continue to equate "cloud computing" with remote, X-as-a-Service, offerings; and this will continue to be a useful distinction, whether or not it is how the term was originally used.

Comment: @MathieuK. I agree with most of your comment. "Cloud Local Server" is technically called Private Cloud (in the new cloud marketing era) and has existed since always

Comment: @Camilo, unfortunately, "Private Cloud" seems to have meanings ranging from "resources allocated to a single consumer" to "local server". "Cloud Local Server" seems contradictory to me, and fails at **least** the _resource pooling_ characteristic in NIST's definition, and probably the _on-demand self-service_ and _rapid elasticity_ characteristics too. To my thinking, that just leaves _broad network access_ and _measured service_, which sounds a lot to me like just a regular old Internet-facing server.

Comment: Also just found out the other day about the Surface Laptop, an MS laptop named after their family of tablets but without a tablet form factor. Yay, name confusion!

Answer (score 19):

I think it'd make sense to create new tags for every specific topic and not mapping everything to [azure-pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-pipelines), so my suggestion is:

- [vsts-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-build) → [azure-pipelines-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-pipelines-build)
- [vsts-build-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-build-task), [vsts-release-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-release-task) → [azure-pipelines-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-pipelines-task)
- [vsts-build-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts-build-agent) → [azure-pipelines-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-pipelines-agent)

Comment: Agreed, [tag:azure-pipelines-build-task] and [tag:azure-pipelines-release-task] should be merged into a new [tag:azure-pipelines-task]. While there are differences between build and release, the task functionality is the same.

Even the tag description for [tag:azure-pipelines-build-task] says it applies to both.

"Questions on extending the Visual Studio Team Services Build and Release Management system through extensions and custom tasks."

Of the **4** questions that have been asked under [tag:azure-pipelines-release-task], all are applicable to both build and release.

Answer (score 19):

The situation is terrible now.

I see a lot of questions that are related to Azure and **NOT** to VSTS (Azure DevOps) with the tag `azure-devops`, and of course, the question is not related to VSTS (Azure DevOps).

Comment: It's not a great naming scheme, but there's not a lot we can do about it. Keeping the VSTS name will confuse people in the future when the old name is forgotten. I'm gonna blame Microsoft for this one. Perhaps an [edit to the tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-devops/info) would help?

Comment: The tag wiki written well, the problem is that people don't read it... for some reason, people ask a question regarding azure and push the azure-devops tag also.

Answer (score 11):

Why not creating aliases, so both tags are working, and using old ones redirect to posts with new tag? This should work both with tags and research. Least surprise. Least friction.

Comment: Yeah, why mass rename, when we can create synonyms?

Answer (score 3):

All `vsts` should be named `azure-devops` throughout.

We still need to distinguish on the difference in resources and resource providers in Microsoft Azure to this Azure DevOps rebranding: `azure-{Resource}`

The `pipelines` in `azure-pipelines` is not a resource in Microsoft Azure as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
vsts-release -> azure-release-pipeline
vsts-build -> azure-build-pipelines
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed an issue with the on-prem version (and the same applies for MS forums): the full name of the cloud service is "Azure DevOps **Service**(s)", which is separate from "Azure DevOps **Server**", which is the on-prem version.
The problem I've seen is that someone posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097126/azure-devops-server-start-a-scheduled-build-manually) tagged `Azure-DevOps` but they really meant `Azure-DevOps-Server`.
The solution was to fix the tagging issue, but maybe we could think of a better way to differentiate (e.g. rename `Azure-DevOps` to `Azure-DevOps-Service`)?