# Tags overlay the sidebar on question pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

Recently all of the [vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vsts) and its child tags were renamed as [azure-devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops) on Chrome Version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows 10. I'm not sure this is the cause of the issue.

Tags (long tags) coincided with the advertisements:

[image]

Reference: [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323525/packagereference-versioning-wildcard-csproj)

Comment: Repro on Waterfox 56, Windows 7

Comment: In Chrome the tags initially overlay the sidebar and then wrap on to multiple lines correctly after a fraction of a second.

Comment: Repro in Firefox 62 on Windows 10. They should set the CSS property `flex-wrap:wrap` on the tag list parent...

Comment: I have seen a similar behavior when we are searching for questions and someone has selected long tags.

Comment: Which browser? FF 62 & Chrome 69 both appear to wrap properly.

Comment: @Shog9 please see the update 1

Comment: Oh, I see it now. The critical factor here is that it breaks when you *don't* have the inline tag editor privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks very much for reporting this! This will be fixed with our next production build.